# Force tiles to take all the available space

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, grid

I'm developping a news section for a website that consits of tiles in a grid, each tile being a news. I'm trying to make something similar to the Windows 8 start menu, but with tiles of variable height. There are four size of tiles : 1x1, 1x2, 2x1 and 2x2.

Each row of the grid will have room for 5 tiles, if they are 1x1 (so you can fit two 2x1 and one 1x1, for example).

The problem I have is that the tiles will leave a hole if their height doesn't match : 
[image]

In this case I would like the dark blue tile at the bottom left to move up one space and fill the white space in between it and the light blue tile at the upper left corner.

Here is my code so far :

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="tile h2 w2"></div>  
    <div class="tile h1 w1"></div>  
    <div class="tile h1 w2"></div>
    <div class="tile h2 w1"></div>  
    <div class="tile h2 w2"></div>
    <div class="tile h1 w2"></div>          
</div>
```

And CSS :

```
.tile{
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    height: 200px;  
    background: #666;       
}

.tile.h1{height: 200px;}
.tile.h2{height: 400px;}
.tile.w1{width: 20%;}
.tile.w2{width: 40%;}
```

There's a plugin called [Packery](http://packery.metafizzy.co/) that can fix this, but the person I'm working for don't want to use external plugins. I tried to study the code but it's pretty complex and I'm having trouble understanding how it works.

The tiles won't always be at the same place, after a refresh (X amount of time) the news will move up and down the "chain", so the grid layout will not always be the same.

Comment: Tell your client or whomever you are working for that this is the way CSS and the web works. They are not going to move around correctly because the math can not be done with CSS alone.  A plugin such as Isotope or Packery or other grid layout solution is going to have to be used, unless you write your own Javascript solution.

Answer (score 1):

Check out http://masonry.desandro.com/, it's impossible doing this with css only and writing the JS script is quite a challenge but from this plugin-in you can learn how to do it.

Comment: Yea I was just about to suggest masonry.  Ive tried to write the JS script and it is not fun but the plugin takes maybe 30 mins to learn